# Sending parameters having special characters to another batch file from a batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, parameters, special-characters

I have the below code:

**`second.bat` file**

```
echo %~1
echo %~2
```

**`first.bat` file**

```
@ECHO OFF &SETLOCAL
@SETLOCAL EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p User=Enter Username: 
set /p Password=Enter Password: 

call second.bat %User% %Password%
```

If user inputs `Admin` as username and `Admin!23` as password the output produced in `second.bat` echo is as below:

> ```
> Admin
> Admin23
> ```

How can I get the special characters as well in the `second.bat` file like below?

> ```
> Admin
> Admin!23
> ```

Comment: Your `call`ed routine inherits both the variables and the `expansion` state, so in your second routine, you could simply `set user` and `set password` to see the actual values. If you alter these values within the second routine, the altered value will be returned to the calling routine. Since `delayedexpansion` is in effect, a simple `echo` will attempt to expand its argument according to the normal rules. To use the `!`, you need to turn `delayedexpansion` off - either before calling the second routine, or within the second routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends of your possiblities.
Are you allowed to change the `second.bat` file?

Then you should transfer the values by (variable) references instead of values, as `CALL` doesn't work very well with complex values.

**Solution 1:**
Then you can change second.bat to

```
@echo off
echo !user!, !password!
```

**Solution 2:**
If you are not allowed to change second.bat and it requires the password as a calling parameter, you could change `first.bat` to

```
@ECHO OFF
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

set /p User=Enter Username: 
set /p Password=Enter Password: 

set ^"password=!password:"=""!"
setlocal DisableDelayedExpansion
call second.bat "%%User%%" "%%Password%%"
exit /b
```

It only fails when quotes in the password are used, then they are doubled.

**Solution 3:**
Injecting code to second.bat without modifying the file.

Assuming second.bat looks like

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "user=%~1"
set "pwd=%~2"

echo !pwd!
```

Change first.bat to:

```
set ^"Inject=." & (set pwd=^!password^!) & rem #"
call second.bat "%%User%%" %%Inject%%
```

This can handle any password, as the line in second.bat
`set "pwd=%~2"`
will be *modified* on the fly to

```
set "pwd=." & (set pwd=!password!) & rem #"
```

Comment: Fortunately I can edit second.bat so echo !user!, !password! worked.

Comment: The problems are when there are other special characters and carets in the password. Carets are doubled by `CALL` and quotes are getting really worse.

Comment: I don't understand your second solution: why is there no `call` in front of `second.bat`? and why do you pass literal strings `%User%` and `%Password%` to `second.bat`?

Comment: @aschipfl I forgot the `CALL`, the double percents are to avoid problems with caret characters

Comment: But then you still needed to change `second.bat`, like `echo %~1` to `call echo %~1`, isn't it?

Comment: @aschipfl No, as the double percents will already be expanded by the `CALL`

Answer (score 1):

You do not need DelayedExpansion to that point! If you need it after, activate it after! If you echo the last line of your example you will see that the `!` should have been missing as well.

As DelayedExpansion uses the exclamation mark as special symbol it gets deleted.